# How to Move All Active Cells to the First Column

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a Macro that imports text into Excel. My problem is the text is in all different columns. There is only one cell populated per column and my ideal state would move all cells to the column A. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are faster and better ways to do what you need but for now I think this should do what you need.

```
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set wk=Sheet1
Set rng =  wk.Usedrange

For each cel in rng
     if cel.Value <> "" and cel.Column <> 1 then
         wk.Cells(cel.Row,1) = cel.Value
         cel.Value = ""
     End if
Next cel
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me for now. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: This seems to be breaking if the cell starts with an equals sign. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?